# Functional Ramda Passing function parameter outside of scope

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, composition, ramda.js

Take the following example imperative JavaScript example:

```
getAnimalList = (hasCat) => {
  const baseAnimals = { dog: animLib.dog(), bear: animLib.bear()};
  if(hasCat){
    baseAnimals.cat = animLib.cat();
  }
  return baseAnimals
}
```

I am trying to write this code in a functional style with Ramda, but the only way I can do so is by having the functions reach outside of scope:

```
getAnimalList = (hasCat) => {
  const baseAnimals = { dog: animLib.dog(), bear: animLib.bear()};
  return when(always(hasCat), merge({hasCat: animLib.cat()}))(baseAnimals)
}
```

Leaving aside how `animLib` is outside of scope, the way I would fix has `hasCat` from being pass from the outside(**if this is a problem at all**) is the following:

```
getAnimalList = (hasCat) => {
  const baseAnimals = { dog: animLib.dog(), bear: animLib.bear()};
  const mergeCat = when(compose(equals(true), prop('hasCat')), 
              compose(merge({hasCat: animLib.cat()}), prop('baseAnimals')));
 return mergeCat({hasCat: hasCat, baseAnimals: baseAnimals});
}
```

But this makes the code incredibly verbose. Is there a better way to do this? Or is the verbosity just the cost of keeping the code more pure.

Comment: Just write `getAnimalList = (hasCat) => ({ dog: animLib.dog(), bear: animLib.bear(), cat: hasCat ? animLib.cat() : undefined })`.

Comment: Your second snippet seems to miss passing the `baseAnimals` into the `merge`.

Comment: "*I would fix has hasCat from being pass from the outside*" - no, I don't get what your problem with that is at all.

Comment: It makes the code harder to reuse. The composed function that merges the cat object can't easily be moved somewhere else because it relies on the `hasCat` being defined. Also, your first comment will not work because we do not want cat as a property on the object if `hasCat == false`

Comment: But it **does** rely on `hasCat`, pretty much by definition.  So pass it in (and pass in `animLib` as well) and everything remains pure, clean, and easily testable.

Comment: @Bergi, `{foo: 'bar', baz: undefined}` does have at least a somewhat different meaning from `{foo: 'bar'}`.  `Object.keys`, `in`, etc.

Comment: @SepehrSobhani The code in the function is not supposed to be moved elsewhere, it is supposed to be called from elsewhere. And your `getAnimalList` function is declared with `hasCat` as a boolean parameter. There is nothing wrong with that. If you want a second function that does not need `hasCat`, just declare it - and call one from the other to avoid duplication.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Yes, a property with an `undefined` value is a bit different, but it might be a viable solution to whatever problem the OP is facing. Also it's not the best idea to return objects of different shapes from the same function - not sure if that's really necessary.

Comment: @Bergi: Whether they are of different shapes depends upon whether you look at the returned object as a record or as a dictionary.  Since JS objects can serve as either, there's often some confusion.  But if this is viewed as a dictionary of type `{String: Animal}`, then there is no problems that it sometimes includes `'cat'` and other times doesn't.  If it's supposed to be a record, then I agree with `cat: undefined` -- or maybe preferably `cat: null`.  Still, I think the design of the OP makes me lean toward *dictionary*.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Ah, you might be right. In that case, `["dog", "bear", "cat"].reduce((dict, name) => ({[name]: animLib[name](), ...dict}), {})` might be the best approach, and putting `cat` in the original list conditionally

Comment: @Bergi: yes, that looks very nice!  Much more easily extensible

Comment: Sorry guys. It is actually not a dictionary. In case you were curious, the function is supposed to build a yup validation with some fields only appearing conditionally.

Comment: Our record/dictionary distinction is between **records**, which have a fixed list of properties (an address might have fixed fields of `street`, `city`, `country`, etc.) and **dictionaries**, which map arbitrary string keys to a certain type of object, say an address list keyed by name.  Assuming `dog`, `bear`, and `cat` all have some type in common, the result is likely a dictionary for these purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that this would do fine:

```
getAnimalList = (animLib, hasCat) => {
  const baseAnimals = { dog: animLib.dog(), bear: animLib.bear()};
  return hasCat ? merge({hasCat: animLib.cat()}, baseAnimals) : baseAnimals;
}
```

Because Ramda's `when` and `ifElse` are based around predicate functions rather than boolean values, using them seems to be overkill here.

Obviously if you want a version that has `animLib` in scope, you can curry this function, either with something like Ramda's [`curry`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#curry) or just by changing to

```
getAnimalList = (animLib) => (hasCat) => { /* ... */ }
```

Then you can create `newAnimalList = getAnimalList(myAnimLib)`.